# How to display accented Latin letters

Tags: r, character-encoding, diacritics

I would like R to return me the same "é" as when I first saved it:

```
someLetter <- "é"
print(someLetter)
[1] "é"
```

But this gave me `"\303\251"` instead.

How can I get R to output me the same accented letter?

If this question has already been answered elsewhere, do comment below with a link! Thanks!

Comment: It depends on your locale. Mine is en_US.UTF-8 and it is correctly displayed.

Comment: @Pascal Thanks! I just changed my locale.

Comment: Perhaps rather than editing your question you could post this as an answer.

Comment: Please post it as an answer, or it will forever erroneously dwell in the land of unanswered questions.

Comment: Roger that, guys. @MikeWise, Nick K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer. I simply set the following:

`system("defaults write org.R-project.R force.LANG en_US.UTF-8")`